# Modify Ruby DBI Row Directly

Tags: ruby, dbi

I have the following method that works fine. However, I think it is ugly. I am coming from the PHP world and am just learning Ruby. Is there a better way to write this method?

```
def _get_tasks(project_id)  
    _tasks = $dbh.select_all("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE project_id=? ORDER BY name ASC;",project_id)
    tasks = []
    _tasks.each do |t|
        _t = t.to_h
        _t[:log] = $dbh.select_all("SELECT * FROM log WHERE task_id=? ORDER BY start DESC;",t[:task_id])
        tasks.push _t
    end
    return tasks
end
```

My initial thought (and hope) would be the follow, but it is wrong because apparently the elements of the tasks Array aren't actually hashes but DBI:Row objects. Any pointers?

```
def _get_tasks(project_id)  
    tasks = $dbh.select_all("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE project_id=? ORDER BY name ASC;",project_id)
    tasks.each do |t|
        t[:log] = $dbh.select_all("SELECT * FROM log WHERE task_id=? ORDER BY start DESC;",t[:task_id])
    end
    return tasks
end
```

Comment: Why do you use global variables? You rarely never need those. Also, have you tried `row.by_field(:log)`?

Comment: The global variable is to share a single database connection through the entire program. And `row.by_field(:log)` won't work because there isn't a column named "log". I'm trying to grab the rows from the log table for a certain task and add them as an arrow to my task hash from the tasks table.

Comment: So then I don't understand what this code does. No, a DB row is not a hash, it's a DB row. Just create a new hash and like you already did if you really need to (which I doubt). Also, global variables are *never necessary*. You should split your project into separate modules and inject dependencies like the DB connection here as constructor arguments to the objects who really need them.

Comment: Oh and by the way, the solution to your problem is: Use classes to model the database tables and only ever access the data through those models. There already exist excellent ORM libraries like DataMapper or ActiveSupport to build these wrappers for you, no need to issue SQL queries by hand. You can then easily extend these models to provide access to their associated data, like you seem to try and do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a bunch of comments suggesting you avoid the global and use classes or an ORM. They're right, but I'm not going to fix that for you.  If you just want this one function to be "prettier" and more idiomatic ruby, drop all the ugly underscores and temp vars and use enumerations.

```
def get_tasks project_id

  task_sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE project_id=? ORDER BY name ASC;"
  log_sql  = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE task_id=? ORDER BY start DESC;"

  $dbh.select_all( task_sql, project_id).
  map(&:to_h).
  map do |task|
    task.merge :logs => $dbh.select_all( log_sql, task[:task_id] ).map(&:to_h)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for actually answering my question. :)